# pylint doesn't work correctly when pylint_django loaded

Tags: django, visual-studio-code, pylint

When `pylint-django` is installed error messages like `Class 'MyModel' has no 'objects' member` disappear. But with them being disappeared some real errors are skipped too. For example, the line `MyModel.objectss.all()` will not throw an error (note two `s` in the word `objects`).

Actually, I find it quite interesting, how `pylint` is marking errors:

- `MyModel.objects.all()` (everything is correct) - gives no error.
- `MyModel.objectss.all()` (two `s` in `objects`) - gives no error.
- `MyModel.objectss.alll()` (two `s` in `objects` and three `l` in `all`) - gives `Class 'MyModel' has no 'objectss' member`.
- `MyModel.objects.alll()` (three `l` in `all`) - gives no error.

It's like at least two errors must occur in order for `pylint` to throw an error.

I am working with`Visual Studio Code 1.39.1`, `pylint==2.4.2`, `pylint-django==2.0.11`

My `Visual Studio`'s `settings.json` file looks like this:

```
{
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--load-plugins=pylint_django"
    ]
}
```

So, is this a bug or is there something wrong with my config?

Comment: Is there any message or error on Output tab on your VS Code?

Comment: @ToanQuocHo Do you mean when I actually run the code? Then yes, of course the code fails.

Comment: No, I mean when you run pylint on your code. Let's say you run `pylint your_file.py ----load-plugins=pylint_django`, is it works? And when you use VSCode, does Output tab on your VSCode displayed any error or messages?

Comment: @ToanQuocHo after running your command it shows only minor improvement suggestions (nothing about `objectss`). VS's Output tab with Python selected in drop down menu doesn't show any error either. Only those very suggestions just like from `pylint`'s output.